# MS Flow to Move file inside Sub-Folder in Document Library dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, ms-flow

I am creating MS Flow to move files between libraries.
Source & destination libraries contains same folder structures & Subfolders.
When file is created in source sub-folders, it should move to respective subfolders dynamically to Destination Library based on where they created on source.

In Move File Scope, i chose Destination Folder: FolderPath/FileNamewithExtension

but I got error.

Please advise me on this.

Comment: which error you've got? Any screenshots? Why are you moving these files?

Comment: {
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Failed to verify the existence of destination location at 'https://site.sharepoint.com/TestNew/Test/' due to error 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'.\r\nclientRequestId: dd176c96-296b-4d12-bdb7-d37429d5cd2f\r\nserviceRequestId: dd176c96-296b-4d12-bdb7-d37429d5cd2f"
}

Comment: and whats the source and destination? It looks like you are setting bad values

Comment: Actually If I select Manually the folder names are working fine but dynamic its not working.. I am almost finding the other ways to do..

Answer (score 1):

In Move file action, you should choose the destination folder like this: /Destination Library/FolderName.

Here is my sample flow to move files, hope it will help you:
[image]

Comment: Manual it is working fine..

Comment: but dynamically we need to fetch subfolders so I have used the formula split and concat and assign it to destination folder. now its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

To-fetch sub-folders name at Run-time we need use the following formula

> **split(triggerBody()?['{Path}'],'/')[1])**

In **Move File** Scope **Destination Folder** section we need to use split function with *FolderPath* using character ('/') and concat with Destination Library name

> Concat('Destination Folder Name','/',
>   split(triggerBody()?['{Path}'],'/')[1]) )